# C++ Constant Array of Member Function Pointers

Tags: c++

I have looked at a lot of posts on arrays of member function pointers, but none that quite answer exactly for me.  This is an embedded application, with no functional or dynamic allocation.

Basically I want a constant (in flash program memory) array of structures, each of which contain some member function pointers to private members.  I would prefer not to manually specify the size of the array.

I have simplified it down to this example.  This does not compile due to constexpr evaluation before class definition is complete.  I am guessing this means before the class "Example" definition is incomplete.

Can someone please help show me how I could achieve this?  Preferably without any complex programming if possible.

```
#include <array>

class Example
{
    private:

    bool SetOne(const char * strVal);
    bool SetTwo(const char * strVal);
    
    struct Param
    {
        using SetValueFunc = bool (Example::*)(const char * strVal);
        constexpr Param(const char * n, SetValueFunc s) : Name(n), SetValue(s) {}
        const char * Name;
        SetValueFunc SetValue;
    };

    static constexpr std::array cSupportedParameters =
    {
        Param("One", &Example::SetOne),
        Param("Two", &Example::SetTwo)
    };
};
```

Comment: Making `Param` and the class methods public, and NOT making `cSupportedParameters` a class member works. Is that a dealbreaker? To maximize information hiding one can play some games with `friend`s, and limit the exposure. The key is to move `cSupportedParameters` out of its class.

Comment: Thanks @SamVarshavchik, but yes, keeping the members private is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array for this, you can define a function that returns the array:

```
static constexpr std::array<Param, 2> cSupportedParameters()
{
    return {
        Param("One", &Example::SetOne),
        Param("Two", &Example::SetTwo)
    };
}
```

As for deducing the array size automatically, I can't think of a clean way to do that. At least if you get the count wrong with respect to how many entries are in the initializer list, it will result in a compilation error. So it should be simple to keep this up to date when you add methods.

Comment: Good suggestion.  What is the effect of using this at runtime?  for example for (auto & p : cSupportedParams())

Comment: What do you mean? The effect would be that you loop through the array. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/s74f41E41

Comment: Thanks for making that example.  Sorry, what I meant by runtime, was will a copy of the array be made each time cSupportedParameters() is called.  It returns an array, not a reference, so I assume a temporary is made for the array iterations?  Sorry, running at about the limit of my constexpr knowledge here!

Comment: It's a `constexpr` -- that means the array is basically a literal. No, it is not copied.

Comment: OK, thanks.  From what I can see in compiler explorer, a copy appears to be made for each use.  I increased the number of table rows to 120 items.  A 360 byte copy is made before the for loop.  Even with -O3.

Comment: That's strange. So, is there any particular reason you need it to be `constexpr`? For instance, you could change the function to return a const reference instead of being constexpr, then inside the function define a static array and return it. This should not result in a copy when looping.

Comment: Yup, that is what I ended up doing...  Thanks.